# react-native link fails on realm

Tags: react-native, realm

I have next versions of react-native / react-native-cli:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1  
react-native: 0.47.2
```

After installing realm with

```
npm install --save realm
```

I'm getting an error

[image]

Next part was solved, was left in case it will help to solve the entire problem < solved part begin

If I run

```
react-native link
```

or

```
react-native link realm
```

I'm getting an error:

```
pathToProjectHere/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/lib/Terminal.js:141
    this._nextStatusStr = util.format(format, ...args);
                                              ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (pathToProjectHerenode_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (pathToProjectHere/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/runServer.js:18:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

solved part end >

I'm still getting an error about realm constructor, even after successful link command 
What's wrong and is there any workaround?

I can not start the new project with realm as well - same error.

[Link to issue on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1340)

Comment: Adding the complete error might help more to understand the problem.

Comment: @bennygenel, done

Comment: `react-native install realm` does a good job installing & linking. Maybe you should try that?

Comment: @ArchNoob, seems like a better solution, than installing and linting with npm. but I'm receiving the same error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an issue and my problem was in lack of understanding RN and Expo. As my project was created using **create-react-native-app**, my project initially was attached to expo. To use Realm, I had to [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think realm has acknowledge this issue and has given *manual* alternatives for it.

Please see the page that they are reffering to you for the issue: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/index.html#missing-realm-constructor and follow it's steps.

But I would recommend first taking a look at [their installation guide](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#installation) which they eleborated a step by step way of handling this issue as alternatives after:

`react-native link` or (something like) `react-native install realm` failure.

I'm writing these steps but highly recommend reading the installation guide so to stay updated.

1. Add the following lines to `android/settings.gradle`:

```
include ':realm'
project(':realm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'../node_modules/realm/android')
```

2. Add the compile line to the dependencies in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':realm')
}
```

3. Add the import and link the package in `MainApplication.java`:

```
import io.realm.react.RealmReactPackage; //   <<====   add this import

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new RealmReactPackage() //   <<====    add this line
        );
    }
}
```

I also see you [made this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1340) there have been [likely issues](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1128)

*Also, I can't indent the code any better, edits are welcome*

Comment: cool, thank you, but I've already checked this and 've done this. no luck yet

Comment: btw, this error on iOS Device in app running with expo

Comment: The issue seems to be very specific now, but when I check with `npm outdated` I see latest react-native is `react-native 0.48.4` and the wanted one is `react-native 0.45.1`. See: https://imgur.com/a/hHwRb . Advice, I think you should either try to upgrade (0.48.4) / downgrade (0.45.1) `react-native` versions and see if it helps. @VladHatko